# Printing diagonal from top-right to bottom-left of matrix python 2

Tags: python, matrix

have a question regarding my code, and I'm really lost 
I need to create empty diagonal list outputting number from maxtrix from top-right ot bottom-left so it is [5, 9, 13, 17, 21].

```
matrix = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

diagonal = []
for posi in matrix: 
    diagonal.append(posi[len(matrix)-1])

print diagonal
```

This is how far I got but it only outputs the last set of the numbers.

I can only change the value of

```
for posi in ##here##: 
    diagonal.append(##here## ##here##)
```

Options I have are:

```
matrix[posi]
matrix
range(len(matrix)-1)
posi
[len(matrix)-1]
[len(matrix)-1-posi)
posi
And like [4][0], [3][1], [1],[2]
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

It been trying to figure it out and lost now, any help is greatly appreciated Thank you

Comment: `for posi in range(len(matrix)-1): diagonal.append(matrix[posi][len(matrix)-1-posi])` note slight error in the option `[len(matrix)-1-posi)` needs to be a `]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use one of those options, I'd go with:

```
for posi in [0,1,2,3,4]: 
    diagonal.append(matrix[posi][len(matrix)-1-posi])
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the thing is I have to choose from the option that I have, not create different code.

Comment: @lufee:  I understand now.  Updated

Comment: more generic would be `for posi in range(len(matrix)-1):`

Comment: @AChampion:  Thanks, better.  I didn't look at all the options close enough - just grabbed one that worked.

Comment: @AChampion:  I changed back.  Using the range(len(matrix)-1) misses the final index.

Comment: Very true - need to drop the `-1` on the range call

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, here is the simple solution with [Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
diagonal = []
for i, j in enumerate(matrix):
    diagonal.append(j[-(i+1)])

# or using list comprehension along with enumerate
diagonal = [j[-(i+1)] for i, j in enumerate(matrix)]

print diagonal
```

Answer (score 0):

While the option being looked for is probably:

```
for posi in range(len(matrix)):
    diagonal.append(matrix[posi][len(matrix)-1-posi])
```

This isn't very pythonic and generally you would iterate over the matrix vs. indices and just use a negative index to count from the back, so a simple list comprehension:

```
diagonal = [row[-posi] for posi, row in enumerate(matrix, 1)]
# [5, 9, 13, 17, 21]
```